# Retrieve country/state and industry lists from Salesforce using the Metadata API and C#

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I'm creating a form on a website that enters the lead directly into Salesforce, using the Enterprise API, which is going just fine.

I'd like to replace my hard-coded paired drop-down list of countries/states, and the list of industries, with the pick lists available within Salesforce, but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to navigate through the Metadata API.

Has anyone had any success with this?

I've tried the methods of listMetadata and describeMetadata, but can't seem to retrieve anything that is anywhere near what I'm after.

Thanks in advance!

I'm using C#, .NET 4, and the WSDL service references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have these defined as picklists in salesforce, then you don't need the metadata API, you can use [describeSObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm) from the enterprise API to get the picklist values. (the picklist values will be contained in the field structure for the relevant field)

Comment: Thank you superfell, will take a look now! :)

Comment: You are such a help! I was guided towards the Metadata API for this part of the work and have wasted so much time in there trying to work just where it was - this has helped enormously, thanks! :D

Comment: Hi again superfell - just a quick question. It seems the list of states is a complete list of a valid states, regardless of the country; I can't seem to find any reference between the state and a country it is valid for. I was hoping the state data could come back with a valid country in the data, but it's only coming back as an id and a value, I can't see a "parent" id in the data. Any ideas?

Comment: @Marc There is `validFor` field which determines what country the state applies to, but it is a binary field where you have to figure what bit is set. But even if I figure that out how do I know what country that bit represents?! Hopefully knows of a better way to retrieve this info...